# Flutter: Slider in BottomNavigation bar causes it to go to the top on the screen

Tags: flutter

Im trying to have a navigation bar with a slider and some buttons on a bottom app bar, but i found that when i initially added in my slider widget it caused my BottomAppBar to go to the top of my screen and so without the use of main axis alignment it will not remain at the bottom. is there a reason that the slider or my layout causes such an issue ?

Code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text("Title"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        centerTitle: true,


        actions: <Widget>[

          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            minWidth: 1,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
          //Title( color: Colors.black,),
          // title:Text("Title_Data"),backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,centerTitle: false,
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            minWidth: 1,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(
              Icons.bookmark_border_outlined,
              size: 25,
            ),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            minWidth: 1,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.workspaces_filled),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            minWidth: 1,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.brightness_4_outlined),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
        ],
      ),


      bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.black87,
            child: new Row(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  minWidth: 1,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
                  shape:
                      CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                ),
                Text(
                  "0",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Slider(
                  inactiveColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                  value: _currentSliderValue,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  divisions: 100,
                  label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
                  activeColor: Colors.tealAccent,
                  onChanged: (double value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentSliderValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Text(
                  "100",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  minWidth: 1,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
                  shape:
                      CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),


      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Text(
              "Image Goes Here",
              softWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Image.network(
                'https://i.imgur.com/KqM0AMm.jpg',
                width: 400,
                errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
                    StackTrace stackTrace) {
                  return FlatButton(
                    textColor: Colors.black,
                    minWidth: 1,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(Icons.error),
                    shape: CircleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                  );
                },
              )),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

[image: With slider and axis align]

With no alignment
[image: With no alignment]

Comment: yes you are using a column as the first widget for bottomNavigationBar so either position it yourself using Positioned bottom 0 or use BottomNavigationBar widget from flutter

Comment: ahh ok, thankyou !

Comment: no problem bard :)

Answer (score 1):

mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

```
 bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          BottomAppBar()
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if BottomAppBar is the first child of bottomNavigationBar and it has columns as a children, it will cause this issue. mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min should be set to explicitly changing default positioning behavior of the widget like the following:

```
     bottomNavigationBar:
                        Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // this column and this line solves the issue
children: [
                      BottomAppBar(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: OverflowBar(
                              overflowAlignment: OverflowBarAlignment.center,
                              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[
    // your columns here
        Column(children :[
        ]),
        Column(children :[
        ]),
        Column(children :[
        ]),
        )),
        ])),
```